# Add a style to html and body via onclick

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem with my hamburger menu, my background page scrolling when it is open. I noticed that if I add 'overflow: hidden' to the body and html, it fixes the problem. However, when I close the menu, the body is obviously still locked. How can I add javascript to cancel these styles from the body and html?

This is what I have tried:

```
<div class="navbar_toggle" onclick="nonscroll(this)">

<script>

 function nonscroll(elem) {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.html.style.overflow = "hidden";
}
</script>
```

When I click the button, I want these styles to apply. When I close the menu, I want them to disappear. Is there a very simple way to fix this?

Comment: you should have a variable that controls the toggle. Right now, it doesn't know when to show or when to hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Copy from this example, paste into your page:

```js
function FixScrollToggle (node) {
  var target = document.body;
  
  function isClicked () {
    return target.classList.contains('fixScrollToggle--on');
  }
  
  function freeze() {
    target.classList.add('fixScrollToggle--on');
  }
  
  function unFreeze() {
    target.classList.remove('fixScrollToggle--on');
  }
  
  
  function onClick (e) {
    if (isClicked()) { return unFreeze(); }
    return freeze();
  }
  
  node.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  Array.prototype.slice.
    call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-apply-fix]')).
    forEach(FixScrollToggle);
});
```

```css
.fixScrollToggle--on {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #c00;
 }
```

```html
<div class="navbar_toggle" data-apply-fix>Click me</div>
```

It's not the *most easy way*, but it's a *clean and relatively easy way*. Just put the JS code into a `<script>` tag in your page.

---

**Explanation**

This code works by adding a `click` eventlistener to each HTML element which has a `data-apply-fix` attribute set. This way, you can attach the same behaviour to multiple elements on your page.

The behaviour of manipulating the CSS is entirely done with the CSS class `fixScrollToggle--on`. This way, you have a very clean separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Simple ways to do that is using toggle class on click listener, as your code above it could:

```
var toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar_toggle')[0];
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var all = [html,body];

toggle.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  for ( var i=0; i < all.length; i++ ) {
    all[i]classList.toggle('is-active');
  }
});
```

Then ur css should be:

```
html, body {
  overflow: auto;
}

.is-active {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;  // prevent body scrolling for safari and ios
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `nonscroll()` function, you need to do two things:

1. Check if `nav` is `hidden` or `shown`.
2. When you know the nav visibility, you can update style for `body` and `html`.

---

```
<div class="navbar_toggle" onclick="nonscroll(this)">

<script>
    function nonscroll(elem) {
        // check if navbar is hidden or shown
        // if nav is hidden: "body overflow is 'hidden'"
        // else "body overflow is 'static'"
        var nav = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar_toggle");
        var nav_hidden = (window.getComputedStyle(nav[0]).visibility === "hidden")

        if(nav_hidden) {
            document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
            document.html.style.overflow = "hidden";
        } else {
            document.body.style.overflow = "static";
            document.html.style.overflow = "static";
        }
    }
</script>
```